# How can I run a Xcode 7 playground on Xcode 6?

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode6

I want to start learning Swift but I am not familiar with Xcode. On the developer apple site you can download a playground that you can use while learning from their book "The Swift Programming Language". But I use an older version of Xcode (v6.2), and the playground is made for version 7. Is there a way of opening the playground without upgrading to the latest version of Xcode? Thanks

Comment: Why don't you want to upgrade to Xcode 7?

Comment: If I want to upgrade to Xcode 7, I also have to upgrade my OS. I have installed the new OS (El Capitan) and compared with Mavericks (what I am running now), and my mbp is a lot slower when it runs on El Capitan. So I want to keep using Mavericks until I buy a new mbp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can't**. The only workaround is to copy and paste the code.

Comment: Technically, there's an exception: Xcode 6.4 can open a simple Xcode 7 Playground (simple = no multiple pages, no use of the new features - a newly created one, basically).

Comment: Ok I understand. Unfortunately the playground I want to open contains about  11 pages. But if I understand correctly, I can make a new project en than drag an drop the files of the Xcode 7 playground in my new project?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'drag and drop'. File scope level code is not allowed in libraries/apps, so you won't be able to compile it into a project. However, you can create new 11 playgrounds and copy the code into them.

Comment: `copy and paste the code` will be very limited anyway because the new code will probably be using Xcode 7's Swift 2 features that OP would have to convert back to Swift 1.2 for Xcode 6... not really ideal.